# Displaying table data with PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to display two sets of data from a table but i keep getting a general server error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error). The first set of data under "Listing of pending applications" is meant to display data from the table "EOI_AC_Data" where the entry in the field "choice1_offer" is "N", originally when i created this php file and was only displaying that data it worked fine, it's when i added in the second query did it start coming up with a server error. The second query is mean to dispaly the exact opposite which is display the data from the table where the entry in field "choice1_offer" is "Y". Here is my code :

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a");
mysql_select_db(twa312, $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM EOI_AC_Data WHERE choice1_offer = 'N'";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM EOI_AC_Data WHERE choice1_offer = 'Y'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn) or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
?>

<p><b>Listing of pending applications</b></p>

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>
<p><a href="comments_form.php?appid=<?php echo $row["ApplicationID"]?>">
<?php echo $row["ApplicationID"]?></a>
<?php echo $row["given_name"]?>
<?php echo $row["family_name"]?>
<?php echo $row["dob"] } ?></p>

<p><b>Listing of completed applications</b></p>

<?php while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) { ?>
<p><?php echo $row2["ApplicationID"]?>
<?php echo $row2["given_name"]?>
<?php echo $row2["family_name"]?>
<?php echo $row2["dob"]?></p>

<?php } mysql_close($conn); ?>
```

Any sort of help would be great as i am new to these languages and am stuck on this problem.

Comment: Place `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', true);` after the opening `<?php` tag, it should help provide some insight.

Anthony.

Comment: @AnthonySterling but how can it display the errors if the page doesn't load at all? I just get "The website cannot display the page"

Comment: Have you tried it? You're getting the 500 because of an error, adding the aforementioned code should help display that error.

Comment: @AnthonySterling yes, i added that line at the start of my code just below the opening <?php tag but i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a solution but. (because your code appears fine)

Why are you getting this message?

1. Error with an .htaccess file
2. PHP Coding Timing Out

Looking at your code its probably #2.

Why do I say that? Because wrong syntax in the while loops will cause a timeout.

**Solution**:

The only help I can give is a suggestion to debug. Remove the loops one by one and see if the error is caused by either one.

If you find which loop it is double check any commented code or anything else that might lead to the error.

Comment: It was in fact an issue within my while loop, i had to move a closing } and add a mysql_close at the end of one of the loops.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to use `;` at below line

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

EDIT 1: again your code have error. correct

```
$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
$rs2 = mysql_query($sql2, $conn) or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: I tried your edit as well but i still seem to be having the same problem

Comment: then you have problem with your connection. try `$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa312", "dam6av9a") or die (mysql_error());` . are you sure your db is in localhost?

Comment: Yes, i am sure it is in localhost as i have previous PHP files using the same details which access the databse fine

Answer (score 0):

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

So you need to replace:

```
<?php echo $row["dob"] } ?></p>
```

with:

```
<?php echo $row["dob"]; } ?></p>
```

and your code will work properly assuming SQL connections and queries are correct.

PS: You should use MySQLi or PDO instead of `mysql_*` functions, which are deprecated. [More information available here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).